# Does floating point length value make sense on pixel unit?

Tags: css, pixel

When I try write stylish CSS for [forums.asterisk.org](http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=81808) site, I saw they use floating point length value on [pixel unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units), for example: `font-size: 13.1px;`.

As far as I known, pixel is the smallest unit in screen, so does floating point length value make sense on pixel unit？

### Screenshot

[image: forums.asterisk.org site use floating point length value on pixel unit]

Comment: A font size should be defined in points IMHO. It's been going on that way for nearly 600 years, no reason to stop now.

Comment: @EJP well, at that time, pixel wasn't born yet. and sometimes (such as display pictures by using color text in HTML) pixel is the best choice to define font size.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's fine, the CSS recommendation allows numbers (not only integers) as values for pixels. Note that `px` is actually defined in terms of `in` in the [recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths):

> `‘px’`: pixels; 1`px` is equal to 1/96th of 1`in`

All in all `13.1px` will be the same as `0.1364in`, where `13px` would be `0.1354in`. The difference is small, but noticeable.

That being said, you should use relative values in my opinion instead, and `pt` for the overall base size.

Comment: yes, the CSS recommendation allows real numbers. but if the media is screen, then what's the difference between `13.1px` and `13px`, i mean, you can't divide one pixel into ten 0.1 pixels, pixel is the smallest unit in screen. and i didn't see other CSS selectors (which may use relative length values and may make fraction becomes integer) inherit from that selector in that page.

Comment: There is a distinction between device pixels and display pixels. For instance, if you're on a retina device and the user has zoomed the document, tenths of a pixel will make a noticeable difference. In this case the display pixels do not map 1:1 to device pixels.